# Getting backslash on JSON

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, spring-mvc

What would be the Java POJO class for below "datapoints"?
datapoints are not constants their values and quantity and counts can increase or decrease.

This below is the output I'm getting from my code where I get backslash.

```
[
    {
        "id": "346id71",
        "arg": {
            "test1": "pass",
            "task": "true",
            "direction": "right"
        },
        "datapoints": "{\"1694473620\":0.0008208249347420499,\"1694509620\":0.0008401434897869077,\"1694545620\":0.0008438824499876583,\"1694581620\":0.0008171293069653031,\"1694617620\":0.0008596749524634415,\"1694653620\":0.0008368097665295172}"
    },
    {
        "id": "346id72",
        "arg": {
            "test1": "pass",
            "task": "true",
            "direction": "left"
        },
        "datapoints": "{\"1694473620\":0.0008208249347420499,\"1694509620\":0.0008401434897869077,\"1694545620\":0.0008438824499876583,\"1694581620\":0.0008171293069653031,\"1694617620\":0.0008596749524634415,\"1694653620\":0.0008368097665295172}"
    }
]
```

This below is the output needed and  but I'm getting backslash in "datapoints" as above

```
[
    {
        "id": "346id71",
        "arg": {
            "test1": "pass",
            "task": "true",
            "direction": "right"
        },
        "datapoints": {
            "1680012000": 0.10124447461480172,
            "1680048000": 8.39834838777665454,
            "1680084000": 8.33850837187659432,
            "1680120000": 8.35752337464636549
            }
    },
    {
        "id": "346id72",
        "arg": {
            "test1": "pass",
            "task": "true",
            "direction": "left"
        },
        "datapoints": {
            "1680012000": 0.123233,
            "1680048000": 3.567384,
            "1680084000": 4.476530,
            "1680120000": 0.0,
            "1680156000": 0.0
          }
    }
]
```

I tried a lot but couldn't figure out proper solution to remove backslash.

this is my model class

```
public class Response {

    private String id;
    private Arg arg;
    private String datapoints;
    
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public Arg getArg() {
        return arg;
    }
    public void setArg(Arg arg) {
        this.arg = arg;
    }
    public String getDatapoints() {
        return datapoints;
    }
    public void setDatapoints(String datapoints) {
        this.datapoints = datapoints;
    }
    
    
}
```

input String for datapoints is like this

```
{"1694473620":0.0008232249347420499,"1694509620":0.0008405554897869077,"1694545620":0.0008438824476576583,"1694581620":0.0008171293069653031,"1694617620":0.0008596749524634415,"1694653620":0.0008368097665295172}
```

Comment: _This below is the output I'm getting from my code..._ Please update the question with the code that generates the unexpected output.

Comment: It looks like `Response.datapoints` should be a `Map<String, Double>` (not a `String`).

Comment: What is the _actual_ JSON you are receiving? Where is the data coming from? What does the Java service/controller code look like? Is this coming from a database?

Comment: This is bad `JSON` structure based on the output you want. I haven't tried this but you best bet is to first parse the datapoints as a String because that's how it's structured in the `JSON`. From there, you can use `String` methods to process the individual points. Or use `JSON` to process the String output to the output you are trying to get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have the following structure. I used Jackson to handle deserialization/serialization, and Lombok to handle getters/setters/toString for the POJO fields.

As others have mentioned, the type for `datapoints` should be a `Map` of `String` to `Double`.

```java
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Map;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import lombok.Data;

public class ParseJson {
    private static final String SAMPLE_JSON_DATA = "[{\"id\":\"346id71\",\"arg\":{\"test1\":\"pass\",\"task\":\"true\",\"direction\":\"right\"},\"datapoints\":{\"1680012000\":0.10124447461480172,\"1680048000\":8.398348387776654,\"1680084000\":8.338508371876594,\"1680120000\":8.357523374646366}},{\"id\":\"346id72\",\"arg\":{\"test1\":\"pass\",\"task\":\"true\",\"direction\":\"left\"},\"datapoints\":{\"1680012000\":0.123233,\"1680048000\":3.567384,\"1680084000\":4.47653,\"1680120000\":0,\"1680156000\":0}}]";

    private static ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonMappingException, JsonProcessingException {
        Response[] response = mapper.readValue(SAMPLE_JSON_DATA, Response[].class);
        System.out.println("\nOUTPUT :- Object::toString");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(response));
        System.out.println("\nOUTPUT :- ObjectMapper::writeValueAsString");
        System.out.println(mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(response));
    }

    @Data
    private static class Arg {
        String test1, task, direction;
    }

    @Data
    private static class Response {
        private String id;
        private Arg arg;
        private Map<String, Double> datapoints;
    }
}
```

#### Output

Here is the `.toString()` call:

```java
[
  ParseJson.Response(
    id=346id71,
    arg=ParseJson.Arg(test1=pass, task=true, direction=right),
    datapoints={
      1680012000=0.10124447461480172,
      1680048000=8.398348387776654,
      1680084000=8.338508371876594,
      1680120000=8.357523374646366}
  ),
  ParseJson.Response(
    id=346id72,
    arg=ParseJson.Arg(test1=pass, task=true, direction=left),
    datapoints={
      1680012000=0.123233,
      1680048000=3.567384,
      1680084000=4.47653,
      1680120000=0.0,
      1680156000=0.0}
  )
]
```

And the `.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString()` call:

```json
[ {
  "id" : "346id71",
  "arg" : {
    "test1" : "pass",
    "task" : "true",
    "direction" : "right"
  },
  "datapoints" : {
    "1680012000" : 0.10124447461480172,
    "1680048000" : 8.398348387776654,
    "1680084000" : 8.338508371876594,
    "1680120000" : 8.357523374646366
  }
}, {
  "id" : "346id72",
  "arg" : {
    "test1" : "pass",
    "task" : "true",
    "direction" : "left"
  },
  "datapoints" : {
    "1680012000" : 0.123233,
    "1680048000" : 3.567384,
    "1680084000" : 4.47653,
    "1680120000" : 0.0,
    "1680156000" : 0.0
  }
} ]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to reach out to whoever creates the JSON and ask them to restructure it. That being said, here is a way to parse your current `JSON` using `GSON`. The first I noticed is that `\"` all need to be `'`. From there, use a `TypeAdapter` to read the `JSON`. The `POJO` for `DataPoints` should be `Map` in my opinion. Comments in the code!

### Main

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.MatchResult;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;


/**
 *
 * @author blj0011 (sedj601)
 */
public class JavaTestArea {
    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        String jsonArrayString = 
                """
                [
                    {
                        "id": "346id71",
                        "arg": {
                            "test1": "pass",
                            "task": "true",
                            "direction": "right"
                        },
                        "datapoints": "{\"1694473620\":0.0008208249347420499,\"1694509620\":0.0008401434897869077,\"1694545620\":0.0008438824499876583,\"1694581620\":0.0008171293069653031,\"1694617620\":0.0008596749524634415,\"1694653620\":0.0008368097665295172}"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "346id72",
                        "arg": {
                            "test1": "pass",
                            "task": "true",
                            "direction": "left"
                        },
                        "datapoints": "{\"1694473620\":0.0008208249347420499,\"1694509620\":0.0008401434897869077,\"1694545620\":0.0008438824499876583,\"1694581620\":0.0008171293069653031,\"1694617620\":0.0008596749524634415,\"1694653620\":0.0008368097665295172}"
                    }
                ]
                """; 
        
        //This code finds " in datapoints and replaces it with '
        //EX: 
        //This ->    "datapoints": "{\"1694473620\":0.0008208249347420499,\"1694509620\":0.0008401434897869077,\"1694545620\":0.0008438824499876583,\"1694581620\":0.0008171293069653031,\"1694617620\":0.0008596749524634415,\"1694653620\":0.0008368097665295172}"
        //Becomes -> "datapoints": "{'1694473620':0.0008208249347420499,'1694509620':0.0008401434897869077,'1694545620':0.0008438824499876583,'1694581620':0.0008171293069653031,'1694617620':0.0008596749524634415,'1694653620':0.0008368097665295172}"                   
        List<Integer> beginDataPoints = Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote("\"{\"")) // sanitize input and create pattern
            .matcher(jsonArrayString) // create matcher
            .results()     // get the MatchResults, Java 9 method
            .map(MatchResult::start) // get the first index
            .collect(Collectors.toList()); // collect found indices into a list
        
        List<Integer> endDataPoints = Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote("}\"")) // sanitize input and create pattern
            .matcher(jsonArrayString) // create matcher
            .results()     // get the MatchResults, Java 9 method
            .map(MatchResult::start) // get the first index
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
//        
        for( int i = 0; i < beginDataPoints.size(); i++){
            jsonArrayString = jsonArrayString.replace(jsonArrayString.substring(beginDataPoints.get(i) + 2, endDataPoints.get(i) - 1), jsonArrayString.substring(beginDataPoints.get(i) + 2, endDataPoints.get(i) - 1).replace("\"", "'"));
        }        
        
        //This code set up GSON and parse the JSON      
        GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
        gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(Response.class, new ResponseTypeAdapter());
        gsonBuilder.setPrettyPrinting();
        Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();        
       Response[] responseArray = gson.fromJson(jsonArrayString, Response[].class);
        
       //This code prints the Response array objects!
        for(int i = 0; i < responseArray.length; i++){
            System.out.println(responseArray[i].toString());
        }        
    }    
}
```

### ResponseTypeAdapter

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.TypeAdapter;
import com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader;
import com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 *
 * @author blj0011 (sedj601)
 */
public class ResponseTypeAdapter extends TypeAdapter<Response> {

    @Override
    public void write(JsonWriter out, Response value) throws IOException {
        //You do this if needed!
//        out.beginObject();
//        out.name("id").value(value.getId());
//        out.beginObject();
//        out.name("arg").value(value.getArg().getTest1());
//        out.name("dataPoints").value("Todo - datapoints here!");
//        out.endObject();
    }

    @Override
    public Response read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
        Response response = new Response();
        in.beginObject();
        while (in.hasNext()) {
            // should really handle nulls for the strings...
            switch(in.nextName()) {
                case "id" -> response.setId(in.nextString());
                case "arg" -> {
                    Arg arg = new Arg();
                    in.beginObject();
                    while(in.hasNext()){
                        switch (in.nextName()) {
                            case "test1" -> {
                                arg.setTest1(in.nextString());
                            }
                            case "task" -> {
                                arg.setTask(in.nextString());
                            }
                            case "direction" -> {
                                arg.setDirection(in.nextString());
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    response.setArg(arg);
                    in.endObject();
                }
                case "datapoints" -> {
                    String datapoints = in.nextString();
                    //System.out.println(datapoints);
                    Gson gson = new Gson();
                    Map map = gson.fromJson(datapoints, Map.class);
                    DataPoints dataPointsObject = new DataPoints(map);
                    response.setDataPoints(dataPointsObject);
                }                
            }        
        }
        
        in.endObject();
        return response ;
    }    
}
```

### Response

```
/**
 *
 * @author blj0011 (sedj601)
 */
public class Response {
    private String id;
    private Arg arg;
    private DataPoints dataPoints;

    public Response(){}
    
    public Response(String id, Arg arg, DataPoints dataPoints) {
        this.id = id;
        this.arg = arg;
        this.dataPoints = dataPoints;
    }

    public DataPoints getDataPoints() {
        return dataPoints;
    }    
    
    public void setDataPoints(DataPoints dataPoints) {
        this.dataPoints = dataPoints;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Arg getArg() {
        return arg;
    }

    public void setArg(Arg arg) {
        this.arg = arg;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("Response{");
        sb.append("id=").append(id);
        sb.append(", arg=").append(arg);
        sb.append(", dataPoints=").append(dataPoints);
        sb.append('}');
        return sb.toString();
    }   
}
```

### DataPoints

```
import java.util.Map;

/**
 *
 * @author blj0011 (sedj601)
 */
public class DataPoints {
    private Map<String, Double> points;

    public DataPoints(Map<String, Double> points) {
        this.points = points;
    }

    public Map<String, Double> getPoints() {
        return points;
    }

    public void setPoints(Map<String, Double> points) {
        this.points = points;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("DataPoints{");
        sb.append("points=").append(points);
        sb.append('}');
        return sb.toString();
    }    
}
```

### Arg

```
/**
 *
 * @author blj0011(sedj601)
 */
public class Arg {
    private String test1;
    private String task;
    private String direction;

    public Arg(){}
    
    public Arg(String test1, String task, String direction) {
        this.test1 = test1;
        this.task = task;
        this.direction = direction;
    }

    public String getDirection() {
        return direction;
    }

    public void setDirection(String direction) {
        this.direction = direction;
    }

    public String getTest1() {
        return test1;
    }

    public void setTest1(String test1) {
        this.test1 = test1;
    }

    public String isTask() {
        return task;
    }

    public void setTask(String task) {
        this.task = task;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("Arg{");
        sb.append("test1=").append(test1);
        sb.append(", task=").append(task);
        sb.append(", direction=").append(direction);
        sb.append('}');
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

### Output

```
Response{id=346id71, arg=Arg{test1=pass, task=true, direction=right}, dataPoints=DataPoints{points={1694473620=8.208249347420499E-4, 1694509620=8.401434897869077E-4, 1694545620=8.438824499876583E-4, 1694581620=8.171293069653031E-4, 1694617620=8.596749524634415E-4, 1694653620=8.368097665295172E-4}}}
Response{id=346id72, arg=Arg{test1=pass, task=true, direction=left}, dataPoints=DataPoints{points={1694473620=8.208249347420499E-4, 1694509620=8.401434897869077E-4, 1694545620=8.438824499876583E-4, 1694581620=8.171293069653031E-4, 1694617620=8.596749524634415E-4, 1694653620=8.368097665295172E-4}}}
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD SUCCESS
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time:  1.351 s
Finished at: 2023-09-28T14:13:13-05:00
```

Answer (score 0):

> I tried a lot but couldn't figure out proper solution to remove backslash.

I think you can remove the backslash in the datapoints field using the `String.replaceAll()` method:

```
public class Response {

    private String id;
    private Arg arg;
    private String datapoints;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Arg getArg() {
        return arg;
    }

    public void setArg(Arg arg) {
        this.arg = arg;
    }

    public String getDatapoints() {
        return datapoints;
    }

    public void setDatapoints(String datapoints) {
        this.datapoints = datapoints.replaceAll("\\\\", "");
    }
}
```

Comment: No this isn't working, already tried, input source for "datapoints" is like this ```{"1694473620":0.0008232249347420499,"1694509620":0.0008405554897869077,"1694545620":0.0008438824476576583,"1694581620":0.0008171293069653031,"1694617620":0.0008596749524634415,"1694653620":0.0008368097665295172}```